# multiple conditions excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

hello i want to create an multiple conditions formulas if some conditions was met.
i know the logic but i can't use proper if formulas on the excel, i have tried conditions formulas but it will caught an error.
i bring the examples excel files here, if you guys want to look.

what is the best formulas to do it ?

thanks

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/funP4.png)

Comment: Simply show your input then desired output. And then explain logic, how to put obtain that output.

Comment: i don't know is it ok to share the files through here, but i have give some explanations on the pictures above on examples

Comment: First "trick" is to use helper columns ...